# Unable to remove 'certain' empty items inside list

Tags: python, string, list, replace, element

I've been coding for a while, but recently I've come across a conflicting issue. For some reason on the "Third Stage" of the print, there are empty items still in a list. It's odd because a section of the code is supposed to remove all items that are empty, but some still remain . . . .

The only thing I've discovered to be the problem is the string containing two commas that are connected "`,,`" and **that** in-between won't get removed.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve this issue, nor found anything to help with my situation.
Thank you in advance for any help you give!

```
SpecificPlayerChat = "!get specific player chat log:  ,   ,, ,,, username | category"
#Removing all spaces found within the string
SpecificPlayerChat = SpecificPlayerChat.replace(" ","").strip().replace("\n","")
print("First Stage:", SpecificPlayerChat)

#Store the string username & category data only and split the rest into a "junk" string
junk,SpecificPlayerChatData = SpecificPlayerChat.split(":")
print("Second Stage:", SpecificPlayerChatData)
junk = "" #This string deleted the unwanted string

#Split the usernames and categories into two separate strings
usernames,categories = SpecificPlayerChatData.split("|")
print("Third Stage:", usernames)

#Split the multiple words or "no words" into an item each to be store in a list
usernamelist = []
categorylist = []
usernamelist = usernames.split(",")
categorylist = categories.split(",")

#remove any empty items
print("   Print Empty items:")
for item in usernamelist:
    if item is '':
        usernamelist.remove(item)
        print("     Empty Item Detected!")
print("Third Stage ", usernamelist)
```

Comment: Your `is null` should crash, as it's `None` in python. It's probably not evaluated. I'd look into this.

Comment: ooh oops forgot to remove that when posting this!

But yeah I don't know what I was thinking, I am just tired. But without the null part the ```if item is '':``` works fine but the action after it doesn't work.

Comment: try with `usernamelist = [i for i in usernamelist if i]` (otherwise your program will crash because you're iterating on the same list you're trying to remove items from). If you still have "empty" items in it and you're not controlling your input, my guess would be that you have non-printable characters in those strings

Comment: Well, that worked! Thanks a lot! But if you don't mind, could you answer me how ```usernamelist = [i for i in usernamelist if i]``` works? Thanks!

Comment: No problem and will do! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are modifying the list while iterating over it.
Try this:

```
usernamelist = [i for i in usernamelist if i]
```

In this case `if i` is like `if len(i) > 0`. In general, remember that `'' == False`.

If you want to keep the loop, then use `enumerate()`

```
for i, item in enumerate(usernamelist):
    if item == '': #you can use "if not item:" instead
        usernamelist.remove(item)
        print("     Empty Item Detected!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this print is showing?

```
print("     Empty Item Detected!")
```

Try this instead of remove:

replace this for:

```
for item in usernamelist:
if item is '' or item is null:
    usernamelist.remove(item)
    print("     Empty Item Detected!")
```

with this:

```
for item in usernamelist:
if item is '' or item is null:
    del usernamelist[usernamelist.index(item)]
    print("     Empty Item Detected!")
```

refs : https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp , 
       https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index

Comment: Tried. I even tried exploring the method but unfortunately to no avail. I also fixed my mistake of writing ```or item is null```. My bad! But it doesn't have any effect on the problem.

Also, the ```print("     Empty Item Detected!")``` is to repeatedly show how many items it found and deleted in the list.

If you run the whole code it should print everything nicely for you.